# Is it possible to do Insert and Delete in a same query in Oracle10g?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, cursor

My requirement is that , I need to insert some records from my `SOURCE` table to `TARGET` table based on some conditions[Conditions I am fetching from `ANOTHER` table that runs through a cursor]. Soon after the insertion into the `TARGET` table I need to delete the records from my `SOURCE`. This flow continues until the `CURSOR` gets empty.

Since I have lot of records in my table its taking time. Is it any other simple way to achieve this??

Whatever i mentioned above is that i'd written inside a stored procedure.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you might have to write a trigger function, in which if the **primary key** in both tables are equal, then the record on the table **source** containing that **primary key** to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you can't "in the same query"
2. It sounds, though, like you might be making a lot of round trips to and from the server.  This *could* be optimized.
3. One approach might be to assign a trigger to your insert (to do the appropriate "delete's" without your application having to initiate them)
4. Another might be to write a stored procedure (that does *all* the work possible on the server side, without *any* extraneous round trips).

This link might help:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Developing-Simple-PL-SQL-Stored-Procedures-for-CRUD-Operations/

Answer (score 1):

The [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081030) statement can eventually delete some matching records.

In the following example you can notice that a table containing four records after a merge can be affected by inserts, updates and deletes all at once.

```
SQL> create table xxx as
  2  select rownum as rn, 'xxx' as pla
  3  from dual
  4  connect by rownum < 5
  5  /

Table created
SQL> select *
  2  from xxx
  3  /

        RN PLA
---------- ---
         1 xxx
         2 xxx
         3 xxx
         4 xxx
SQL> merge into xxx tgt using (
  2         select rownum as rn,mod(rownum,2) as even_odd
  3         from dual
  4         connect by rownum < 6
  5     ) src on (tgt.rn = src.rn)
  6  when matched then update set tgt.pla = null
  7     delete where even_odd = 1
  8  when not matched then insert(rn,pla) values (src.rn,'XXX')
  9  /

5 rows merged
SQL> select *
  2  from xxx
  3  /

        RN PLA
---------- ---
         2 
         4 
         5 XXX

SQL>
```